# Deleting s3 (Standard IA) Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a legacy S3 bucket (with data no longer required) that is 8TB - however the objects that I can see using the console only amount to approx 100mb.

I can see that there is a lifecycle policy on the bucket to transition to Standard-IA, and then permanently delete. These actions make objects noncurrent at day zero, and then moves noncurrent versions to Standard-IA at day 30. Then at day 365, all noncurrent versions are permanently deleted.

Bucket versioning is also enabled.

I would like to know what the most cost efficient way to delete this bucket is. My understanding is that although DELETE operations are free, LIST operations are not (and this is likely used). I believe this would occur if changing the lifecycle policy to delete files from 365 to say 1 day. Is there another option? Does the 'empty' option in the console remove all files without incurring an expense?

Comment: Posted a solution, did it clarify?

Comment: Thanks for your response, and for the links to the docs.

Having a look it appears that although the deletion API does not incur a cost, the GET requests that are first required to delete them will (e.g., $0.005 per 1,000 objects) - It appears that the 'empty' button option on the console does this, so will instead suspended versioning and then change the lifecycle policy to remove the files after N days.

Thanks again for your help

Comment: Can you share the link where you see the empty button performs list operation before deletion?

Comment: I have updated the answer with appropriate link to api which works behind the scenes of empty bucket, if the helps do accept it so that it may help others in the future with a similar problem

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer and including the link - I have accepted this as resolving the question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a lifecycle policy and delete operation  will be **free !!!** , but a bucket empty option will not be free as **behind the scenes empty bucket option will perform list operation before deletion.**

> For lifecycle policy

According to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-expire-general-considerations.html)

- **You are not charged for expiration or the storage time associated with an object that has expired.**

> For 'empty' option

According to [pricing page > requests and data retirevals](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)

**DELETE and CANCEL requests are free** but it will cost you a small amount (not stated directly) because the api to [delete objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObjects.html) **requires to know the keys before deletion**.

Behind the scenes of empty bucket option

> It calls a LIST on the bucket, pagination through the objects in the bucket 1000 at a time. It calls a DeleteObjects API method, deleting 1000 at a time.
> The cost is 1 API LIST call per 1000 objects in the bucket. Delete operations are free, so there's no extra cost there